# gRPC generated file doesn't have json definition

Tags: go, microservices, grpc, protoc

I'm trying to generate Go file from proto file but it doesn't have json definition in the method's input definition. Should I add the json definition by myself or there were something wrong with my script. Thank you, I sincerely appreciate your help.

Proto file

```
message RateRequest {
    string Base = 1;
    string Destination = 2;
}
```

Generated file

```
type RateRequest struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    //No json definition here
    Base        string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=Base,proto3" json:"Base,omitempty"`
    Destination string `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=Destination,proto3" json:"Destination,omitempty"`
}
```

Protoc script

```
protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
--go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
protos/currency.proto
```

grpcurl

```
grpcurl --plaintext -d '{Base: "GBP", Destination: "USD"}' localhost:9092 Currency.GetRate
// Error invoking method "Currency.GetRate": error getting request data: message type RateRequest has no known field named base
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the error is

> error getting request data: message type RateRequest has no known field named base

And the `json` is

```
json:"Base,omitempty"`
```

Then it seems it's looking for the wrong field, it should be

```
json:"base,omitempty"`
```

Comment: Thank you I ran grpcurl with `grpcurl --plaintext -d '{"Base":"GBP", "Destination":"USD"}' localhost:9092 Currency.GetRate` and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked :)